# get access to my pc localhost from my mobile device by internet-sharing

Tags: macos, apache, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, sharing

I have a mac book pro 10.7.4 osx which is running a web server apache accessible through `http://localhost/`.
Then I share my connection through internet-sharing wi-fi.

From my mobile device I can navigate thanks to this sharing connection.
My question is:
will it be possible by using "internet sharing" get access to my localhost from my mobile device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access to your PC from your mobile device by IP address. Something like 'http://192.168.0.2/' where you should put your PCs IP instead of '192.168.0.2'

If you want to access the PC over domain name, you can setup simple DNS server inside your home network which will map domain name to IP.